# Can I use the ! operator on a property?

Tags: ios, objective-c, properties, operators, not-operator

Is it possible to use the `!`(not, or bang) operator on a property? The reason I would want to do this is because I might find a property that does the exact opposite of what I want it to do. Here is an example of what I have in mind.

```
GKMatchRequest *request = [[GKMatchRequest alloc] init];
request.minPlayers = 2;
request.maxPlayers = 2;
request.!playerGroup = MyMap_Forest | MyRulesCaptureTheFlag;
```

I got this example from the [Apple Docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GameKit/Reference/GKMatchRequest_Ref/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/GKMatchRequest/playerGroup) and modified it.

Here is what the docs say:

> If your game sets the `playerGroup` property, only players whose requests share the same `playerGroup` value are automatched by Game Center. Setting the `playerGroup` property to 0 allows the player to be matched into any waiting match. Set the playerGroup property to a nonzero number to match the player only with players whose match request shares the same player group number.

Comment: so that would just be `request.playerGroup = !(MyMap_Forest | MyRulesCaptureTheFlag);`

Comment: You cannot do what you're looking to do using your proposed syntax. @Leo's syntax is what you need.

Comment: Uh, assuming that either `MyMap_Forest` or `MyRulesCaptureTheFlag` is non-zero, then `!(MyMap_Forest | MyRulesCaptureTheFlag)` will always be zero. I doubt that's what's desired.

Comment: If the specified values were bit masks, then the desired result would probably be `request.playerGroup = ~(MyMap_Forest | MyRulesCaptureTheFlag);`. This would invert the bit masks so it included everything but the two groups. But if the values aren't bit masks, this wouldn't work either.

Comment: If this were a bitmask, then this would be a good reason to switch to Swift, where you can manipulate bitmasks _as sets_ and doing what you want to do is trivial. But it isn't so it isn't. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you seem to want to do is not possible. The `playerGroup` property only has two possible semantics: if it's 0, then it matches anything; if it's any non-zero value, then it only matches requests with the same value.

There's no way to achieve "matches anything *except* this value". That has nothing to do with the language or syntax. It's entirely on how Apple defined the `playerGroup` property. The semantics of this is in the implementation, both in the frameworks and on the server side. Hoping that some hypothetical language feature could induce different behavior in those pieces of code is not sensible.